# How to get rows which does not match an ID in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to write a Oracle query which will list down all id,name & file from repo1 which has a matching id in file_repo but no matching id found in repo1_status

```
repo1
id, name    
1,  abc 
2,  def
3,  emm
4,  xdd

file_repo
id, file
1,  a.c
2,  d.c
3,  e.c
4,  x.c

repo1_status
id, status, status_desc
1,  good,   new generated
3,  good,   new generated
```

So far I wrote the below query, which does not work. Any help

```
SELECT repo1.id, name,file
FROM repo1,file_repo,repo1_status
WHERE (repo1.id=file_repo.id and repo1.id!=repo1_status.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
 SELECT repo1.id, name,file_repo
 FROM repo1 INNER JOIN file_repo ON repo1.id = file_repo.id 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM repo1_status WHERE repo1_status.id = repo1.id)
```

[Here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EXISTS) is the link about EXISTS

**OR**

```
SELECT repo1.id, name,file_repo
 FROM ((repo1 INNER JOIN file_repo ON repo1.id = file_repo.id)
      LEFT JOIN file_repo.id ON file_repo.id = repo1.id)
 WHERE file_repo.id is null
```

A `left join` like this is the same as `NOT EXISTS` and it might have a better performance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 SELECT repo1.id, name,file_repo
 FROM repo1 INNER JOIN file_repo ON repo1.id = file_repo.id 
 WHERE repo1.id not in (SELECT id FROM repo1_status)
```